# peewee azure functions avoid MySQL server has gone away

Tags: azure-functions, peewee

do you know what is the best practice to avoid peewee errors that MySQL Server has gone away when using Azure Functions paid based on consumption? Probably there is a best practice to call db.connect() / db.close() like described for other frameworks here http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#framework-integration

The error happens from time to time and is not really predictable.

Thanks for your help and best regards

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a timeout that will kill idle connections - I'm guessing this is the issue. You can try using the [reconnect mixin](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/blob/master/playhouse/shortcuts.py#L174) which handles automatic reconnect attempts under certain error conditions.